# Is there an event fired when a console logs something?

Tags: javascript, events

I want to know if there is an event to hook into when the console logs something. It will be helpful for re-sizing my iframe since the iframe has content loaded by javascript and then the page inside the iframe logs when that content loads.

Comment: You may want to use window.postMessage from one window to the other instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option could be if you would have a common object for handling debugging features like this, and once you want to log something, call a method on it, for example clog().
It would be a wrapper for console.log(), so you can have hooks around the exact call.

Of course you should have to include and use this file/object in every document during development.